# Acting on globals faster than passing them as arguments? [julia-lang]

Tags: performance, parameter-passing, global, julia

I just finished studying Julia (and most importantly the performance tips!). I realized that the use of global vars makes the code slower. The counter-measure to that was to pass as many variables as possible to arguments of functions. Therefore I did the following test:

```
x = 10.5  #these are globals
y = 10.5

function bench1()  #acts on global
  z = 0.0
  for i in 1:100
    z += x^y
  end
  return z
end

function bench2(x, y)
  z = 0.0
  for i in 1:100
    z += x^y
  end
  return z
end

function bench3(x::Float64, y::Float64) #acts on arguments
  z::Float64 = 0.0
  for i in 1:100
    z += x^y
  end
  return z
end

@time [bench1() for j in 1:100]
@time [bench2(x,y) for j in 1:100]
@time [bench3(x,y) for j in 1:100]
```

I have to admit that the results were extremely unexpected, and they are not in agreement with what I have read. 
Results:

```
0.001623 seconds (20.00 k allocations: 313.375 KB)
0.003628 seconds (2.00 k allocations: 96.371 KB)
0.002633 seconds (252 allocations: 10.469 KB)
```

The average results are that the first function, which acts on global variables directly is **always** faster by about a factor of 2, than the last function which has all the proper declarations AND does not act directly on global variables. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Performance Tip 2: "You should not take the results of this [first] run seriously." :)

Comment: I mention "average results". I have run @time at least 5 times before taking this average.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more problem is that the following are still in global scope:

```
@time [bench1() for j in 1:100]
@time [bench2(x,y) for j in 1:100]
@time [bench3(x,y) for j in 1:100]
```

as you can see from the still huge numbers of allocations reported by `@time`.

Wrap all these in a function:

```
function runbench(N)
    x = 3.0
    y = 4.0
    @time [bench1() for j in 1:N]
    @time [bench2(x,y) for j in 1:N]
    @time [bench3(x,y) for j in 1:N]
end
```

warm up with `runbench(1)`, then for `runbench(10^5)` I get

```
1.425985 seconds (20.00 M allocations: 305.939 MB, 9.93% gc time)
0.061171 seconds (2 allocations: 781.313 KB)
0.062037 seconds (2 allocations: 781.313 KB)
```

The total memory allocated in cases 2 and 3 is 10^5 times 8 bytes, as expected.

The moral is to almost ignore the actual *timings* and just look at the *memory allocations*, which is where the information about type stability is.

EDIT: `bench3` is an "anti-pattern" in Julia (i.e. a style of coding that is not used) -- you should never annotate types just with the intention of trying to fix type instabilities; this is not what type annotations are for in Julia.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yes, am I still learning that's why I sometimes I use this "anti-pattern". I am avoiding currently.

However, I am not quite sure how I can extract type stability from the memory allocation just as easily as you did... I mean (I think) that function bench2(x,y) is perfectly type stable as long as the arguments given are floats. Therefore, I would never imagine that there is "something wrong", e.g. I should run `@time` in a local scope.

Comment: For this example, I can see that it is very easy to understand that the bytes allocated should be 8x(number of reps) because I just treat a single floating variable `z` . But what happens when you treat codes that do solving of differential equations for example? How can I use the memory allocation to help me optimize? Please if you ever have free time and would like to help more, write a couple of tips here!

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is mainly because of the compilation time. If I change the "main" code as

```
N = 10^2
println("N = $N") 

println("bench1")
@time [bench1() for j in 1:N]
@time [bench1() for j in 1:N]

println("bench2")
@time [bench2(x,y) for j in 1:N]
@time [bench2(x,y) for j in 1:N]
```

it gives

```
N = 100
bench1
  0.004219 seconds (21.46 k allocations: 376.536 KB)
  0.001792 seconds (20.30 k allocations: 322.781 KB)
bench2
  0.006218 seconds (2.29 k allocations: 105.840 KB)
  0.000914 seconds (402 allocations: 11.844 KB)
```

So in the second measurement, `bench1()` is slower than `bench2()` by a factor of ~2. (I omitted `bench3()` because it gives the same results as `bench2()`.) If we increase `N` to 10^5, the compilation time becomes negligible compared to the calculation time, so we can see the expected speedup for `bench2()` even in the first measurement.

```
N = 100000
bench1
  1.767392 seconds (20.70 M allocations: 321.219 MB, 8.25% gc time)
  1.720564 seconds (20.70 M allocations: 321.166 MB, 6.26% gc time)
bench2
  0.923315 seconds (799.85 k allocations: 17.608 MB, 0.96% gc time)
  0.922132 seconds (797.96 k allocations: 17.517 MB, 1.08% gc time)
```

Comment: Aha! Okay, this looks much more natural and expected. Thank you!